# Need to pass git sha to checkout to Jenkins multi branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Is it possible to use parameters to allow users to pass a git sha to a multi branch pipeline while defaulting to the head of the branch? Also I would only need to this function for the master branch.

I'm using ...
Jenkinsfile in code
Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but I guess you have to use scripted pipelines instead of declarative ones.

- If the current branch is the master, you configure a parameter for this build (as this isn't super intuitive, I wrote a [blog article](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines) a while ago). `params.INPUT_REVISION` for example would then store the given revision and you can set default to `HEAD` or fallback to it, if the parameter is not yet specified (e.g. for the first run).
- You supply this revision to the [`checkout(scm)`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) step as a parameter so that it doesn't checkout the current master branch, but the specified revision.

Comment: I did see where you can skip the default checkout with declarative branches but haven’t tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with declarative pipelines with the following...

```
pipeline {
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
...
steps {
    script {
      if (GIT_REVISION=='HEAD') {
        checkout scm
      } else {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
            branches: [[name: "${params.GIT_REVISION}"]],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
            extensions: [],
            submoduleCfg: [],
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'XXXXXXX', url: 'git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxxx.git']]
        ])
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```